# Ratings criteria chess24

Tags: rating

My rating in chess24 is 1560, is the rating based on my wins or any other criteria considered? I can see the scores change when I win or lose.

Comment: Welcome to Chess Stack Exchange! Please take a moment to read the [tour] and the [help].

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://support.chess24.com/hc/en-us/articles/201200336-What-do-the-ratings-mean-) on their site, "A new member starts with a rating of 1800 and after a rated game that number changes. The change depends on the result of the game and your opponent's strength."

I have no reason to assume this is incorrect or incomplete.  These are probably the only factors.

Comment: I do agree that outcome of the game and the ratings of the opponents play a role. But the change might depend on other factors as well such as "rating reliability" (as in Glicko).